# Помогите разобраться почему скрипт не начинается при подтверждение confirm а ??

Tags: javascript

```
'var sumab = function () {

var a = 0,
    b = 0,
    sum = 0;


// получение целочисоенных значений
a = parseFloat(prompt("введите число а")) || 0;
b = parseFloat(prompt("введите число b")) || 0;

// получение суммы
sum = a + b

// создание функцию модуль числа

var mod = function(arg) {
    if (arg < 0) arg= arg * (-1) ;
    return arg;
}

// проверили на выполнение условие числа

if (mod(sum) > 10 ) {
    alert("не правильные выходные данные")
}else alert(sum)

// выполнение скрипта заново

    var stat = confirm("хотите начать заново??");

    if (stat) sumab;
    else return;
}

sumab();'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var sumab = function () {

var a = 0,
    b = 0,
    sum = 0;


// получение целочисоенных значений
a = parseFloat(prompt("введите число а")) || 0;
b = parseFloat(prompt("введите число b")) || 0;

// получение суммы
sum = a + b

// создание функцию модуль числа

var mod = function(arg) {
    if (arg < 0) arg= arg * (-1) ;
    return arg;
}

// проверили на выполнение условие числа

if (mod(sum) > 10 ) {
    alert("не правильные выходные данные")
}else alert(sum)

// выполнение скрипта заново

    var stat = confirm("хотите начать заново??");

    if (stat) sumab();
    else return;
}

sumab();
```

`if (stat) sumab()` – так Вы вызываете функцию

Comment: понятно !! спасибо

Comment: @ZiyadZiyadxanov отметьте ответ как правильный, если он вас удовлетворил

Comment: я бы с радостью токо не знаю как? я первый раз тут

Comment: @ZiyadZiyadxanov галочка